# Por que diferentes tipos de aspas são usados em lugares como mensagens de erro?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem

Eventualmente vejo aspas diferentes (uma tipo de aspas para "abrir" e outro para "fechar") alguma mensagem, principalmente em mensagens de erro.

Vejamos, por exemplo, uma mensagem de erro emitida pelo Ruby ao avaliar uma referência que não está definida:

```
irb(main):001:0> foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        4: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):2
        1: from (irb):2:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NameError (undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object)
```

Note aqui:

> ```
> 5: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
> ```

Note que, para "abrir", usou-se o símbolo do acento grave (`` ` ``) e, para fechar, uma aspas simples (`'`). Tem algum motivo para esse uso diferente? Não creio que seja um acidente, por isso a questão.

Comment: A formatação do stdout tem mais haver com o Shell, qual é o Shell usado nesse exemplo?

Comment: `zsh`, mas não creio que tenha relação com o shell. Testei no `bash` e a saída foi a mesma.

Comment: Pq nas aspas do stdout coloca-se código, e código em  `backticks\` pode executar funções em vários shells.. mas também gostaria de saber se é isso msm kk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Onde se usa?

Esse padrão de acento grave e aspas simples não é único de mensagens de erro. Veja um exemplo em um trecho do manual do `bash`:

> Brace expansions may be nested.  The results of  each  expanded
> string are  not  sorted;  left  to  right  order  is  preserved.  For
> example, a{d,c,b}e expands into **`ade ace abe'**.

Um outro exemplo um pouco diferente, com dois acentos e duas aspas simples, do mesmo manual:

> -k file: True if file exists and its **``sticky''** bit is set.

## GNU-ismo?

Na [documentação do GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Documentation-Tips.html), na seção de "Dicas para Strings de Documentação", há uma referência para essa convenção de acento grave seguido de aspas simples. Ele é chamado de *backtick-apostrophe notation* e é referido como uma convenção antiga de aspas simples.

No Emacs, quando se `` `escreve' `` dessa forma, o texto fica destacado, o que facilita a leitura de manuais que utilizem essa convenção. O [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsDocumentationNotation) recomenda esse padrão, mas nota que as origens da convenção são incertas.

Em [listas de e-mail do GNU](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2012-03/msg00390.html) vemos que outras pessoas já questionaram a origem, mas a resposta dada por Barry Margolin foi que talvez os autores da documentação do GNU estivéssem, infelizmente, usando uma fonte em que os caracteres parecessem balanceados, ou seja, algo visualmente parecido com `` `palavra´ ``. Porém, a saída para a maioria das fontes foi daquilo que foi realmente escrito, `` `palavra' ``, de forma não balanceada.

Mesmo com a origem não tão certa no ambiente GNU, pode-se afirmar que a herança da convenção hoje em dia é um GNU-ismo.

## Outras possibilidades

Uma outra possível origem é a confusão semântica e visual dos caracteres com suas possibilidades na escrita de forma estilizada:

- `` ` ``: acento grave com código ASCII 96
- `"`: aspas duplas com código ASCII 34
- `'`: aspas simples ou apóstrofo com código ASCII 39
- `´`: acento agudo com código ASCII 239

Hoje em dia, todos os quatro caracteres existem de forma separada no ASCII. Antes disso, alguns encodings de 6-bit tinham caracteres que serviam para múltiplos propósitos semânticos. Um exemplo é o `'` que poderia ser utilizado como acento, aspas e apóstofro.

Partindo dessa análise, pode-se entender que o GNU estabeleceu esse padrão como herança dos tempos do ASCII, em que a maioria das fontes imprimiam os caracteres em questão de forma curvada ou hiper-estilizada.